# Programmatically obtaining the Qt version that was used to create the Qt plugin

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, dll

I am parsing a Qt plugin's metadata and need to get the Qt version that was used to develop the Qt plugin. I have looked into following classes:

```
QPluginLoader
QLibrary
QLibraryInfo
```

And none of them provide that info. Does anyone know what class should I use?

Comment: Do you think you can find a hint in the .pro file used?  It's not exact obviously, but maybe could help narrow things down a bit

Comment: @Huytard, I looked at the .pro file, nothing there